# Apache activemq artemis v.2.28.0: How to set on demand whether a message has an expiration time or not?

Tags: producer-consumer, activemq-artemis

I'm learning how to use the Artemis messaging broker. In my example application, I'm applying a producer-consumer scheme. I want some messages that are sent to a queue to have an expiration time. My sample application is developed in Spring Boot. I use the following method to send messages:

```java
public void send(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate, String queueName, String textMessage, long timeToLive) throws JMSException {
    jmsTemplate.setTimeToLive(timeToLive);
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queueName, textMessage, new MessagePostProcessor() {
        public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws JMSException {
            message.setJMSExpiration(timeToLive);
            return message;
        }
    });
}
```

I have defined the following configuration in the broker.xml file:

```xml
<address-setting match="#">
    <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
    <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
    <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
    <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
    <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
    <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
    <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
    <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
</address-setting>
```

With this configuration, I have checked through the management console that the messages have the Expiry field set to 0 even if I set a value other than 0 in the timeTolive field. I have modified the configuration of the broker.xml file to this one:

```xml
<address-setting match="#">
    <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
    <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
    <expiry-delay>1000</expiry-delay>
    <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
    <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
    <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
    <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
    <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
    <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
    <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
    <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
    <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
    </address-setting>
</address-settings>
```

With this configuration the opposite is true. If I set the timeToLive field to 0, the Expiry field does not show the value 0 and shows the timestamp of when the message will expire. I don't understand why.

Could you give me some orientation on how to solve this problem? Is it possible to set on demand whether a message has an associated expiration time or not?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to use the [`setJMSExpiration()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSExpiration-long-) method, but this is not allowed and will have no impact on the message. The JavaDoc for this method states:

> This method is for use by JMS providers only to set this field when a message is sent. This message cannot be used by clients to configure the expiration time of the message. This method is public to allow a JMS provider to set this field when sending a message whose implementation is not its own.

Instead you should use the [`setTimeToLive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html#setTimeToLive-long-) method on the corresponding `MessageProducer` or [`JMSProducer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/JMSProducer.html#setTimeToLive-long-).

Comment: I didn't notice that detail, I added the setJMSExpiration() method because when I set the value 0 in setTimeToLive() an expiration value was set (well, when I monitored the queue in the management console an expiration value was observed in the Expires field) but I guess it is done by the configuration that has been set in the broker.xml file. Would it be missing to set some configuration in the broker.xml file?